# Table border not showing - even with class .table-bordered

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

So I am creating an email template, i have included a table inside, but as you can see from the code when it displays, it doesnt shows table border. I want to have the normal single line table border. I have tried adding in "class="table table-bordered" but it still doesnt show me the border. How can i solve this?
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head> 
    <title>Mizona</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
    <style type="text/css">
      #logo img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: block;
      }

      td {
        word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; font-family:'Verdana', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight:normal; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0; 
      }
      
      img {
        max-width: 100%;
      }

      .desktop-only {
        display: block;
      }

      .mobile-only {
        display: none;
      }

      .align-center {
        text-align: center; 
      }
      
      #cta1 a {
        text-decoration: none !important;
        color: #FFFFFF !important;
      }

      .no-spacing {
        padding:0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }

      #socialicons img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: inline-block !important;
        border: none;
      }
      #graphic img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: inline-block !important;
      }

      table[class="body"] .columns td.one {
        width: 8.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.one {
        width: 8.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.two {
        width: 16.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.two {
        width: 16.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.three {
        width: 25% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.three {
        width: 25% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.four {
        width: 33.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.four {
        width: 33.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.five {
        width: 41.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.five {
        width: 41.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.six {
        width: 50%;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.six {
        width: 50%;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.seven {
        width: 58.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.seven {
        width: 58.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.eight {
        width: 66.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.eight {
        width: 66.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.nine {
        width: 75% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.nine {
        width: 75% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.ten {
        width: 83.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.ten {
        width: 83.333333% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.eleven {
        width: 91.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.eleven {
        width: 91.666666% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .columns td.twelve {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      table[class="body"] .column td.twelve {
        width: 100% !important;
      }

      table[class="body"] .columns td {
        padding-top: 10px;
      }

      .pad-right-10 {
        padding-right: 10px;
      }

      .pad-top-10 {
        padding-top: 10px;
      }
      
      .mobile-center {
        text-align: left !important;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

        .pad-right-10 {
          padding-right: 0px;
        }

        .desktop-only {
          display: none !important;
        }

        .mobile-only {
          display: block;
        }
        
        .mobile-center {
        text-align: left !important;
        }

        .center-mobile {
          text-align: center;
        }

        #logo img {
          width: 100% !important;
        }

        #logo-mobile img {
          width: 80% !important;
        }
        #graphic img {
          width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
        }
        *[class].center {
          text-align:center !important;
          margin:0 auto !important;
        }
        *[class].bottom-pad{ padding-bottom:35px !important;}
        table[class="body"] table.columns td {
          width: auto !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] table.column td .list {
          width: auto !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] img {
          width: auto !important;
          height: auto !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] center {
          min-width: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .container {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .row {
          width: 100% !important;
          display: block !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .wrapper {
          display: block !important;
          padding-right: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .columns {
          table-layout: fixed !important;
          float: none !important;
          width: 100% !important;
          padding-right: 0px !important;
          padding-left: 0px !important;
          display: block !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .column {
          table-layout: fixed !important;
          float: none !important;
          width: 100% !important;
          padding-right: 0px !important;
          padding-left: 0px !important;
          display: block !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .wrapper.first .columns {
          display: table !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .wrapper.first .column {
          display: table !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] table.columns td {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] table.column td {
          width: 100% !important;
        }

        table[class="body"] .columns td {
          width: 100% !important;
          display: block;
        }
        table[class="body"] .column td {
          width: 100% !important;
          display: block;
        }

        table[class="body"] td.offset-by-one {
          padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] td.offset-by-two {
          padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] td.offset-by-three {
          padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] td.offset-by-four {
          padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] td.offset-by-five {
          padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] td.offset-by-six {
          padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] td.offset-by-seven {
          padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] td.offset-by-eight {
          padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] td.offset-by-nine {
          padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] td.offset-by-ten {
          padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] td.offset-by-eleven {
          padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] table.columns td.expander {
          width: 1px !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .right-text-pad {
          padding-left: 10px !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .text-pad-right {
          padding-left: 10px !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .left-text-pad {
          padding-right: 10px !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .text-pad-left {
          padding-right: 10px !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .hide-for-small {
          display: none !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .show-for-desktop {
          display: none !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .show-for-small {
          display: inherit !important;
        }
        table[class="body"] .hide-for-desktop {
          display: inherit !important;
        }

        .social-icon td img {
          width: 40px !important;
          height: 40px !important;
        }
      }
    </style> 
  </head> 
  <body style="width:100% !important; min-width:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; text-align:left; margin:0; padding:0; background:#eeeeee; "> 
    <table class="body" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse;  vertical-align:top; text-align:left; height:100%; width:100%; background:#eeeeee; margin:0; padding:0; " bgcolor="#EEEEEE"> 
      <tbody> 
        <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
          <td class="center" align="center" valign="top" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:center; font-weight:normal; margin:0; padding:0; "> 
            <center style="width:100%; min-width:600px; "> 
              <table class="container" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:inherit; width:600px; background:#ffffff; margin:0 auto; padding:0; " bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
                <tbody> 
                  <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
                    <td class="center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; margin:0; padding:0;" align="left" valign="top"> 
                      <table class="row" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:100%; position:relative; display:block; padding:0px; "> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0;" align="left" bgcolor="#353937"> 
                            <td class="wrapper last center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; position:relative; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; margin:0; padding:0px; " align="left" valign="top"> 
                              <table class="twelve columns center desktop-only" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:600px; padding:0; display:table !important; "> 
                                <tbody> 
                                  <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
                                    <td class="center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; margin:0; padding:0px; " align="left" valign="top"> 
                                      <div class="mktEditable" id="logo" style="" mktoname="logo">
                                        <p class="no-spacing" style="margin: 30px;"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/Major-Infrastructure-Issue_Email-Template_Logo.png" alt="eO Logo.png" constrain="true" imagepreview="false" style="max-width: 600px;" /></p>
                                      </div></td> 
                                  </tr> 
                                </tbody> 
                              </table> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table> </td> 
                  </tr> 
                </tbody> 
              </table> 
              <table class="container mktoContainer" id="template-wrapper" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:inherit; width:600px; background:#ffffff; margin:0 auto; padding:0; " bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr class="mktoModule" style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" id="content-intro-simple" mktoname="content-intro-simple"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 40px 10px 40px"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="heading-simple" style="" mktoname="heading-simple">
                      <p><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/Major Infrastructure Issue_Email Template_Customer Action Required.png" /> <br /> <br /></p> 
                      <h4 style="color: #2ea049; font-size: 18px; line-height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Upcoming Security Changes</h4> 
                      <div> 
                        <br /> 
                      </div> 
                      <p><b>Customer Name,</b></p>
                      <p>We are committed to ensuring the highest level of security standards for your most valuable digital assets. This email is requesting your partnership on some important security initiatives.</p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" id="content-intro-simpled47b52d3-01b4-4053-9a68-431c4cec6c29" mktoname="content-intro-simple-clone"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 40px; background-color:#EFF2F2"> 
                    <table  style="width:100%; background-color:white"> 
                      <tbody> 
                        <tr> 
                          <td align="center" width="20%"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/Major Infrastructure Issue_Email Template_Icons_What.png" /></td> 
                          <td style="width:70%; padding: 15px;">eOriginal is upgrading both our password acceptance criteria and the connection types our solution supports.</td> 
                        </tr> 
                        <tr> 
                          <td align="center" width="20%"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/Major Infrastructure Issue_Email Template_Icons_When.png" /></td> 
                          <td style="width:70%;padding: 15px;">Upgrades take effect <span style="color: orange"><strong>March 29th</strong></span> for Preview on Demand, <span style="color: orange"><strong>April 26th</strong></span> for Test on Demand, and <span style="color: orange"><strong>April 28th</strong></span> for Production on Demand.</td> 
                        </tr> 
                        <tr> 
                          <td align="center" width="20%"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/Major Infrastructure Issue_Email Template_Icons_Action Required_orange.png" /></td> 
                          <td style="width:70%; padding: 15px;"><span style="color: black"><strong>Ensure your Financial Assets are Safe with Enhanced Password Requirements</strong></span><br />We are requesting all customers ensure their passwords have a minimum length of 8 characters, 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter, 1 number, and 1 special character. This applies across both user and API-based sessions.<br /><br /><span style="color: black"><strong>Keep Sensitive Data Exchanged between eOriginal’s Platform, Users, and External Systems Private with Strong Encrypted Connections</strong></span><br />Please ensure that your access to eOriginal’s solution, whether through a browser or API, uses TLS 1.2 with a strong cipher suite (detailed in the attached document).</td> 
                        </tr> 
                        <tr> 
                          <td align="center" width="20%"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/Major Infrastructure Issue_Email Template_Icons_Why.png" /></td> 
                          <td style="width:70%;padding: 15px;">These actions provide greater protection from brute force attacks and keep the communication between eOriginal’s solution, your external systems, and user browser sessions secure.</td> 
                        </tr> 
                      </tbody> 
                    </table> </td> 
                </tr>

                <!-- <tr class="mktoModule" style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" id="content-intro-simpled47b52d3-01b4-4053-9a68-431c4cec6c29" mktoname="content-intro-simple-clone"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px; background-color:#EFF2F2"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="heading-simpled47b52d3-01b4-4053-9a68-431c4cec6c29" style="" mktoname="heading-simple">
                      <div> 
                        <br /> 
                      </div> 
                      <p style="color: #2ea049; font-size: 16px; line-height: 120%; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><strong>Ensure your Financial Assets are Safe with Enhanced Password Requirements</strong></p> 
                      <p>All customers will be required to comply with a minimum password policy of 8 characters, 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter, 1 number, and 1 special character. This will be required across user and API-based sessions.</p> 
                      <br /> 
                      <p style="color: #2ea049; font-size: 16px; line-height: 120%; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><strong>Keep Sensitive Data Exchanged between eOriginal’s Platform, Users, and External Systems Private with Strong Encrypted Connections</strong></p> 
                      <p>Any access to eOriginal’s solution, whether through a browser or API, will be required to use TLS 1.2 with a strong cypher suite (detailed in the attached document).</p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr> -->
                
                <tr class="mktoModule" style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" id="content-intro-simpled47b52d3-01b4-4053-9a68-431c4cec6c29cfe45834-9b29-425f-b7e2-ee12f4678d5d" mktoname="content-intro-simple-clone-clone"> 
                  <td style="padding: 10px 40px 20px 40px"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="heading-simpled47b52d3-01b4-4053-9a68-431c4cec6c29cfe45834-9b29-425f-b7e2-ee12f4678d5d" style="" mktoname="heading-simple">
                      <p>Full details on these and other upcoming requirements can be found in the attached document. Should you have any questions or concerns, please feel free to contact our support team and they will route you to the most appropriate resource.</p> 
                      <div>
                         We look forward to partnering with you on these important security initiatives. 
                      </div> 
                      <div></div> 
                      <p>Thank you,</p> 
                      <p><b>Val Daly</b> <br />VP, Customer Services<br /><a href="mailto:support@eoriginal.com" target="_top">support@eoriginal.com</a></p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="social" mktoname="social" bgcolor="#2EA049"> 
                  <td class="two-column" style="font-size: 0; text-align: center;"> 
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      <table width="100%">
                      <tr>
                      <td width="50%" valign="top">
                      <![endif]--> 
                    <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                      <table width="100%"> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr> 
                            <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 12px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 20px 40px;"> <a href="http://go.eoriginal.com/JB3eB005bE0cHk00O000000" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff">eOriginal.com</a> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table> 
                    </div> 
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td><td width="50%" valign="top">
                        <![endif]--> 
                    <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                      <table width="100%"> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr> 
                            <td class="inner" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> 
                              <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%"> 
                                <tbody> 
                                  <tr> 
                                    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://twitter.com/eOriginal/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-twitter-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/57606" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="LinkedIn" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-linkedin-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/eOriginal/58932553996/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-facebook-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px;" width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://www.eoriginal.com/eo-insights/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Blog" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-blog-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                  </tr> 
                                </tbody> 
                              </table> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table> 
                    </div> 
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                      <![endif]--> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="footer" mktoname="footer" bgcolor="#353937"> 
                  <td class="two-column" style="font-size: 0; text-align: center;"> 
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      <table width="100%">
                      <tr>
                      <td width="50%" valign="top">
                      <![endif]--> 
                    <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                      <table width="100%"> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr> 
                            <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> <img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-footer-logo-v2.2.png" width="200" /><br /><br /> <span>© 2019 eOriginal, Inc. All rights reserved.</span> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table> 
                    </div> 
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td><td width="50%" valign="top">
                        <![endif]--> 
                    <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                      <table width="100%"> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr> 
                            <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> The Warehouse at Camden Yards<br /> 351 W. Camden St., Suite 800<br /> Baltimore, MD 21201<br /><br /> SALES <span style="color: #2EA049">1-866-935-1776</span><br />SUPPORT <span style="color: #2EA049">1-866-364-3578</span> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table> 
                    </div> 
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                      <![endif]--> </td> 
                </tr>
              </table> 
            </center></td> 
        </tr> 
      </tbody> 
    </table>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `table-bordered` isn't in your code. You need to define it in your css `<syle>`, something like `.table-bordered { border: 1px solid red; }` and then add it to whatever table you want to have a border `<table class="table-bordered">...</table>`.

Comment: @sallf i tried that already, but the border only shows at the four corners, i wanted to show on every row and column, you get what i mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Add below style to your css

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the output I get from the above css.
[image]

For more information on border for html table, check this link https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/tables/html_table_border.cfm

Below is the updated code

```
.table-bordered {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.“table-bordered” tr, .“table-bordered” td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: HI, this is still not what I'm trying to achieve. The border only shows the 4 corners of the table and not like the image i shared

Comment: @RajveerSingh The same css I have used in the JSFiddle and it is working fine. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/en1tbw8h/.  Is this the way you need? Is it not working in all the browser or only on particular browser? I have updated my previous answer with image output.

Comment: the code works on its own, but in my code that i provided it doesnt work. you can try it there

Comment: Could you please check this https://jsfiddle.net/new4zx8c/. If this is what is needed?

Comment: Could you please take screenshot and mark the portion?

Comment: Its close. I only need the border for the table in the body. Now its showing border for the whole email

Comment: @RajveerSingh. Ok got it. Please check the updated code in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/new4zx8c/1/. Something like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189440/discussion-between-sriram-and-rajveer-singh).